# Jboss as 7 took very long to get started

Tags: java, netbeans, jboss

When I want to start my jboss AS 7 server, it took very long to get started. I am using netbeans 7.4

and how actually this jboss AS 7 functioning? should I start the server from the standalone.bat file? or from the netbeans?

10:34:15,303 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
10:34:15,422 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
10:34:15,456 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting

it will come up like the above, whenever i start my Jboss AS 7 Server. It is normal but then it take really long time.I dont know when it will started :wondering:

Comment: Have you considered turning up the logging level within JBoss to see what it is doing?  Set the logging level to DEBUG to see what is happening or what the last line in the log is before things seem to stop or slow down significantly.

Comment: oo ok i will try it out :D

Comment: I would start with running the standalone.bat first to make sure it works okay without any netbeans interaction, which it should. Then you can try running it inside netbeans.

Comment: I'm using jboss-as-7.1.1.Final and it's taking a long time too using the `[JBOSS_HOME]\bin\standalone.bat` script (on Windows). Debug log does not appear to show any errors. Server doesn't actually start at all.

Answer (score 4):

Ah, looks like I was using a JDK 1.8 release. I switched to JDK 1.7 and now the server starts.
Maybe this is the same solution for you?