# JBoss AS not starting up on Mac OS?

Tags: java, macos, jboss, jboss7.x

I downloaded the JBoss AS 7.1.1 from [here](http://jbossas.jboss.org/downloads/).

Set up the JBOSS_HOME and other variables as mentioned.

After that when I run `./standalone.sh`, it gets stuck on the following:

```
     ./standalone.sh 
=========================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: /Users/pbane3/Desktop/Servers/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final

  JAVA: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java

  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+TieredCompilation -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone.xml

=========================================================================

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
11:56:22,651 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
11:56:22,776 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
11:56:22,805 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
```

What can be the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got the answer:

1. Had to download jdk 1.7
2. Run the following command:

   ```
   export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7`
   ```
3. Then in the installation bin folder:

   ```
   ./standalone.sh
   ```

Hope helps the future readers.

Taken help from the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22621932/1475228).